# Pass the name of the object property in the HTML in angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have a html where I need to pass the object name/string in the html. For example:

HTML

```
<app-family
(callDad) ="callFamily($event, {{family.Dad}})""   // I want to pass "Dad" as a string
(callSon) ="callFamily($event, {{family.Son}})""   // I want to pass "Son" as a string but get it from the object so it is not error prone
(callMom) ="callFamily($event, {{family.Mom}})"" // I want to pass "Mom" as a string 
(callDaughter) ="callFamily($event, {{family.Daughter}})"" // I want to pass "Daugher" as a string 
></app-customer>
```

Component Class

```
export class Family  {
  family: Family;
}
```

Model

```
export class Family{
  Dad: string
  Mom: string
  Son: string
  Daughter: string
}
```

I want to get the name of the property and pass it in the html. Like Dad, mom, son and daughter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 passing a value from html template to a method in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087795/angular-4-passing-a-value-from-html-template-to-a-method-in-a-component)

Comment: @DmitryS. No I am not looking to get value but actual object string like Dad, mom

Comment: @LearnAspNet Please check my answer and let me know is it work for you or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think have solution for you. Please check and try my code and the given stackblitz demo link =>
**HTML:**

```
<app-family
(callDad) ="callFamily($event, showPropName(family,family.Dad))"
(callSon) ="callFamily($event, showPropName(family,family.Son))"
(callMom) ="callFamily($event, showPropName(family,family.Mom))"
(callDaughter) ="callFamily($event, showPropName(family,family.Daughter))"
></app-family>
```

**TS:**

```
showPropName(property, value)
{
    for(var i in property)
    {
        if (property[i] == value)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Demo Link => [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/buttonclick-muqysh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). Demo link contains 2 button. On button click property name is displayed in the console. 
So, I think using this process you can pass property name to any method.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is `enum`.

Model:

```ts
export enum Family {
  Dad = 'Dad',
  Mom = 'Mom',
  Son = 'Son',
  Daughter = 'Daughter',
}
```

In the ts component you need to import ’Family’:

```
family = Family;
```

In the HTML component:

```
callFamily($event, family.Dad)
```